# How to handle/replace null values in snowflake tables with empty string at table level

Tags: null, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have many snowflake table which multiple columns with datatype TEXT or varchar having NULL values. I wanted to replace all the NULL values to empty string or blank at table level. I am looking for a way apart from NULLIF and COALESCE as they will work at column level and it is not feasible to specify 100's of columns.

Sample data :

```
 A    B     C     D
 1   test  NULL  NULL
99   NULL  test  test
```

Desired output :

```
 A    B     C     D
 1   test         
 99         test  test
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve the desired effect with Snowpark and Python:

```
WITH replace_nulls AS PROCEDURE(table_name TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'main'
AS
$$
def main(session, table_name):
  session.table(table_name).replace(None, '').write.mode('overwrite').save_as_table(table_name)
  return table_name + ' NULL handling completed'
$$
CALL replace_nulls('test_tab');
```

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test_tab(A INT, B TEXT, C TEXT, D TEXT)
AS
SELECT  1,   'test',  NULL,  NULL UNION
SELECT 99,   NULL,  'test',  'test';

SELECT * FROM test_tab;
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

*The code is just sample, it does not check the column data type, etc.

More at: [Snowflake - invoking Python code without creating UDF/Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74159933/snowflake-invoking-python-code-without-creating-udf-stored-procedure) and [Snowflake Python UDFs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-creating.html)

Comment: Thank you @Lukasz Szozda. Appreciate your answer. Will this also work for recurring creation of tables? The process is defined like I have to create 400 tables daily and data coming from source has these NULL values and I need to replace it with blanks. How can I apply loop to iterate on all 400 tables list?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, there is no way to specify such behavior for text/varchar columns on table level.

To automate the replacement for your table, you may write a stored procedure, which is looping over all columns and is generating a corresponding UPDATE-statement.