# Is it possible to insert into Snowflake from Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to insert into a Snowflake table from Power Bi.  Previously, I have leveraged the following YouTube video ([Bulk Writeback to SQL from Power BI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgIhsF7kEjI&t=428s)) from Bi Elite to writeback to a MySQL database.   Now I'm trying to do the same with a Snowflake database, but I'm not having any success.   The steps that I utilize for the MySQL writeback are (all detailed in the Bulk Writeeback Video):

1. Create a custom column in my table that mimics the insert statement that I want.
2. Create a function that connects to the database and uses the custom insert column as an input and performs the insert.

The function in step 2 relies upon the NativeQuery function in Power Bi to perform the insert.  That function looks like this:

```
    (insert_statement as text)=>
let
    Source = MySQL.Database("localhost:3306", "mydatabase", [ReturnSingleDatabase=true]),
    insert = Value.NativeQuery(Source, insert_statement)
in
    insert
```

Then you simply create an INSERT column using invoke custom function feature. This column executes the insert statement in Step 1 and performs the insert.

When I try this with my Snowflake database it doesn't work.  I believe the issue is related to the connector used to connect to Snowflake, Snowflake ODBC Connector.  It appears that this connector does not support the Value.NativeQuery function that I use in my function to perform the insert.  Is anyone aware of an alternative function that will work with SnowFlake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to execute INSERT INTO query from Power BI via M-language function.

**Power BI**:

```
(insert_statement as text) =>
let
    source = Snowflake.Databases("<locator>.snowflakecomputing.com","<warehouse_name>"){[Name="<database_name>"]}[Data],
    insert = Value.NativeQuery(source, insert_statement, null, [EnableFolding=false])
in
    insert
```

[image]

---

Important **`[EnableFolding=false]`** otherwise every query will be wrapped with outer select query and cause SQL syntax error.

[image]

---

**Snowflake Setup:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST.TAB(col1 TEXT);
```

Direct insert SQL text will succeed in inserting value but it will error out:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Workaround - Stored procedure**

Creation of stored procedure to be used for inserting new values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST.INSERT_VALUES(input VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TEST.TAB(col1) VALUES(:input);
  RETURN 'Row successfully inserted';
END;
```

Call from Power BI:

```
CALL TEST.INSERT_VALUES('Test - insert from PowerBI');
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

State on Snowflake:

[image]

Warning! This approach should be thoroughly tested(it may not work if Power BI uses caching or reusing call for the same input).

---

**Extras: Invoke INSERT INTO without stored procedure**

Running an arbitrary code via [CALL (with Anonymous Procedure)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74159934/5070879):

```
WITH proc AS PROCEDURE(str TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'main'
AS
$$
def main(session, str):
  return session.sql(f"{str}").collect()
$$
CALL proc('INSERT INTO TEST.TAB(col1) VALUES (''Test - insert from anonymous function - inline PowerBI'')');
```

Call from Power BI(one-liner):

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: How did you create an invoke function? I can't seem to find anything on it.

Comment: @jun SP: TEST.INSERT_VALUES was created using Snowsight UI directly on Snowflake. Code provided in the answer