# Unable to connect to snowflake in power bi

Tags: sql, powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Syntax written works in Snowflake but doesn't work when I connect to snowflake in power bi

Details: "ODBC: ERROR [42000] SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 4 at position 4 unexpected 'set'.
syntax error line 7 at position 0 unexpected ')'."

below is the code I wrote

```
set IP_EVENT_TYPE_ID = '*';
    select CriticalityLevelDescription, CriticalityLevelID, Department, DeviationID, EventTypeID
    from QUALITY_DEVIATIONS.CV_0346_SJ_QIMS_DEVIATIONS
```

Comment: Error message indicates that native query is used with query folding enabled. Setting `[EnableFolding=false]` should solve it. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74909698/5070879 and [Use Value.NativeQuery function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/native-query-folding#use-valuenativequery-function)

Comment: can you re-write for me to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query would look something like this:

```
let 
 sql = "set IP_EVENT_TYPE_ID = '*';
    select CriticalityLevelDescription, CriticalityLevelID, Department, DeviationID, EventTypeID
    from QUALITY_DEVIATIONS.CV_0346_SJ_QIMS_DEVIATIONS",
 source = Snowflake.Databases("<locator>.snowflakecomputing.com","<warehouse_name>"){[Name="<database_name>"]}[Data],
    data = Value.NativeQuery(source, sql, null, [EnableFolding=false])
in
  data
```

Comment: I get the logic now. It worked