# Upsert Pandas Dataframe into Snowflake Table

Tags: python, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, upsert

I'm upserting data in snowflake table by creating a Temp Table (from my dataframe) and then merging it to my Table. But is there a more efficient way of achieving it ? Like merging directly the dataframe on snowflake table without a temp Table ?

Because I will do it on several tables having a few thousant rows.

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import pd_writer

engine = create_engine('snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account_identifier}/{database_name}/{schema_name}?warehouse={warehouse_name}&role={role_name}'.format(
            user='user',
            password=os.environ['SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD'] ,
            account_identifier='account_identifier',
            database_name='DB_NAME',
            schema_name='SHCEMA_NAME',
            warehouse_name='WH',
            role_name='ADMIN'
        )
)
conn=engine.connect()
temp_table_name='source_table'

df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'description':['a','b','c']})

#create temp table in snowflake
res_sql=df.to_sql(temp_table_name.lower(), engine, if_exists='replace',index=False, method=pd_writer, schema='SCHEMA_NAME')

#MERGE TEMP TABLE TO EXISTING TABLE
conn.cursor().execute(
            '''
            MERGE INTO target_table USING source_table 
            ON target_table.id = source_table.id
            WHEN MATCHED THEN 
                UPDATE SET target_table.description = source_table.description
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
                INSERT (ID, description) VALUES (source_table.id, source_table.description);
            '''
)

#Drop temp table 
conn.cursor().execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DB_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.source_table")
```

Comment: As I understand, it's also creating a temp table, what make this solution better ? Is it faster ?

Comment: Could you elaborate? If you are referring to sample code `target_df` is just for demo purposes. It could be your actual table already existing at Snowflake.

Comment: You are right. I read the code to fast. This solution is faster or more cost_efficient ?

Comment: I have provided some links in the answer. 1) You operate only using Python code(no inline SQL) 2) Snowpark Python code is for the most data operations directly translatable into SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [snowflake.snowpark.Table.merge](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.Table.merge.html):

> **Merges this Table with DataFrame source on the specified join** expression and a list of matched or not-matched clauses, and returns a MergeResult, representing the number of rows inserted, updated and deleted by this merge action.

Standalone sample(table target exists at Snowflake):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE target(key TEXT, value TEXT);
INSERT INTO target VALUES (10, 'old'), (10, 'too_old'), (11, 'old');

SELECT * FROM target;
```

Python code(here wrapped with `WITH PROCEDURE ... CALL` for simplicity):

```
WITH proc AS PROCEDURE() RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE PYTHON RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8' PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python') HANDLER = 'main'
AS
$$
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import when_matched, when_not_matched

def main(session):
    source = session.create_dataframe([(10, "new"), (12, "new"), (13, "old")], schema=["key", "value"])

    target = session.table("target")
    
    return target.merge(source, (target["key"] == source["key"]) & (target["value"] == "too_old"),
        [when_matched().update({"value": source["value"]}), when_not_matched().insert({"key": source["key"]})])
               
$$
CALL proc();
```

Output:

```
MergeResult(rows_inserted=2, rows_updated=1, rows_deleted=0)
```

[image]

---

Related:

- [Snowpark API](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/index)
- [Snowpark](https://www.snowflake.com/en/data-cloud/snowpark/)
- [Snowflake - invoking Python code without creating UDF/Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74159934/5070879) - for this ad-hoc sample, normally called from client tool

Comment: I compare warehouse usage, snowpark is doing it quicker. Thank's for the solution :)