# Getting Snowpark error: 'Async query is not supported in stored procedure yet' but function not using stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to do a for loop through a table of queries then get those queries to execute asynchronously using collect_nowait() but it tells me this method can't be used on a stored procedure but I'm not using a stored procedure. Has anyone come across this before? Someone also suggested **collect(block=False)** instead but it's still not working. This is my code and the error:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
 
def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    tableName = 'DB.SCHEMA.DDL_TABLE'
    query_table = session.table(tableName)
    df = query_table.toPandas()
 
    for int in df.index:
        command = df["DDL"][int]
        job = session.sql(command).collect_nowait()
        job.result()
    return 'Done'
```

[image]

Comment: Hi - can you update your question with what "command" is actually evaluating to? What happens if you just use collect() rather than collect_nowait()

Comment: When you run Python code from a Python Worksheet it will be wrapped into a stored procedure and that you can see in the Query History. If you look at your query id in Query History you should see something like this in the query text: `with PYTHON_WORKSHEET as procedure () returns ...`

Comment: "but I'm not using a stored procedure" - actually there is an anonymous procedure involved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75899802/5070879

Comment: @Sergiu @ Lukasz Szozda thanks for the info! How then is it possible to use the collect_nowait() method in Snowpark if running Python code from a python worksheet is always wrapped in a stored procedure and async queries aren't allowed in procs? It seems a bit counterproductive unless there's another way? Just a bit confused as to how these things work, I'm new to Snowpark!

Comment: @NickW command is referring to the 'DDL' column from the table which contains rows of queries. If I used collect(), executing the queries wouldn't be asynchronous because apparently collect_nowait() is the async method

Comment: I was wondering whether it was the actual DDL being run that was the issue, rather than the code you've wrapped around it - but from others' responses that seems unlikely. This looks like a documentation gap and is probably worth raising with Snowflake Support - if there are documented functions that cannot be run from a Python worksheet

Comment: @NickW yes it does seem like that, I've asked on the Snowflake forums also but got no useful answers there. I will definitely raise a ticket with Snowflake Support, thanks for the responses!